# Как в txt файле найти строку с каким-то словом и вывести второе слово на этой строке

Tags: python, файлы

Допустим: `(# -*- python -*- #)`
В текстовом файлике есть строки. Есть строка `"Вася Пупкин"`. Я хочу найти строчку с словом `"Вася"`, и вывести второе слово на данной строке (`"Пупкин"`). Так вообще реально?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста - вы хотите извлечь второе слово в строке, содержащей слово "Вася" или слово следующее за словом "Вася"?

Comment: Следующее слово

Comment: Тогда исправь заголовок и вопрос. Сейчас там есть два раза слово "второе", а слово "следующее" - ни разу.

Comment: Так его исправляют админы! Они бесят уже!

Comment: @Vayton, под вопросом есть кнопка ["править"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/940632/edit)... Не понял, чем вас бесят админы?

Comment: Тем, что они правят моё вопрос и он меняет жёстко смысл!

Comment: @Vayton, [вот единственная правка (из ваших двух вопросов)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/940632/revisions) - смысл не был изменен ни на йоту. Админы тратят свое свободное время, чтобы сделать этот сайт более удобным и безопасным, чтобы помочь таким как вы (_безвоздмездно_). Проявите к ним чуточку уважения и благодарности. Для справки -  я не являюсь админом или модератором данного ресурса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FIND = "Вася"

with open("blabla.txt", encoding="utf-8") as  f:          # или другой еncoding=
    for string in f:
        if FIND in string:
            words = string.split()
            ind = words.index(FIND)
            print(words[ind + 1])
            break
```

---

Пример вводного файла `blabla.txt`:

```
Сегодня красивый день.
Завтра будет вторник.
У меня хороший друг, его зовут Вася Пупкин и он из Симферополя.
Я теперь поеду к нему.
```

Вывод:

> ```
> Пупкин
> ```

Comment: Формулировка вопроса достаточно размытая, но я все же склоняюсь к варианту когда автор хочет извлечь строго второе слово в строке, содержащей слово "Вася". Т.е. `words[1]`

Comment: Так нельзя. В зависимости от значения FIND может случиться "ValueError: X is not in list". Например ищем слово "шина", а в строке есть слово "машина".

Answer (score 0):

Разбить строку на список слов. Найти в списке позицию, на которой находится слово "Вася". Вывести следующий за этим элемент списка.

```
>>> s = "Вася Пупкин"
>>> lst = s.split()
>>> lst
['Вася', 'Пупкин']
>>> lst[lst.index('Вася') + 1]
'Пупкин'
```

Comment: Автор пишет про второе слово, а не про следующее.

Comment: Нет. Я хочу вывести следующее слово после слова "Вася"

Comment: Andrey, я не это хотел узнать. Читайте внимательнее вопрос. Я работаю с txt файлом, который подключаю к python'у